# ViewModel used by multiple views

Tags: c#, wpf

In an MVVM pattern, I have a single common ViewModel used by 3 usercontrols. I was instantiating the ViewModel and passing it as a parameter to the constructors of the user controls but this breaks XAML which requires that objects are constructed with parameterless constuctors.

What is the accepted best practise for creating a shared ViewModel?

Comment: Simply assign it to the DataContext property.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a ViewModel for your MainWindow which contains a property of Type `SharedViewModel`: `public SharedViewModel SharedViewModel {get;set;}`. You set the DataContext of your Window to your MainViewModel and bind to the shared ViewModel like:

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <UserControl1 DataContext="{Binding Path=SharedViewModel}"/>
        <UserControl2 DataContext="{Binding Path=SharedViewModel}"/>
        <UserControl3 DataContext="{Binding Path=SharedViewModel}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dependency Injection with Unity ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660899(v=pandp.20).aspx ) or MEF are the standard MVVM ways of coupling views to viewmodels

But don't forget that MVVM is a pattern, not a rigid framework.  You can have a one-line hookup in the view's code behind:

```
InitializeComponent();
this.DataContext = new ViewModel(whatever);
```

without the sky falling.

Comment: Thanks mcalex, if I do this though is a new VM instantiated for each control?

Comment: yes with the new call.  why, will multiple views be open at once?

Comment: No but they're sharing the ViewModel. e.g. I have a forex buy widget, forex sell widget and a globe with forex displays on it all on the same canvas.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add parameterless constructors for your UserControls

```
public MyUserControl() : base(new MyViewModel())
{}

public MyUserControl(MyViewModel viewModel)
{}
```

Note: This may break several design paradigms. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a base view that'll initialize the viewmodel

Comment: Which is loaded on the initial window?